# Android Activity as dialog

Tags: android, listview, dialog

I have an activity with ListView populated by SQLite DB. I would open the activity as a dialog box, select a row and display the content in a TextView of Activity from which I opened the dialog ... the best way? thanks

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder2=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder2.setTitle(getString(R.string.titolo_alert_versione_lite));
            builder2.setMessage(getString(R.string.titolo_alert_testo__lite));

            builder2.setPositiveButton("Google Play",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                      @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=");
                                 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                                 startActivity(intent);


                      }

                      });

                      builder2.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {




                      }

                      });

                      builder2.show();
```

Comment: I only used this so far that I have included in my post above

Comment: Alright, looks good. What was your question again?

Comment: simple, How do I open my Activity as a dialog box? sorry but I am new to Android

Comment: You can't. A dialog box is always displayed _on top_ of an activity.

Comment: @user2895164 You should unaccept your answer from Jeremy Miller and accept the one from Ryan Schultz. His answer is of a much superior form since his answer contains no links and actually trys to explain a concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList for how to add a use a list as a dialog and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout for using your own custom layout -- both provide examples.

Answer (score 1):

Your description doesn't make a whole lot of sense, but I think what you're saying is:

1. You want to open an activity "as a dialog", let someone pick a row
2. Once the row is picked, set a textview to the contents of that row on the previous screen

Rolling with this you could either go with a dialog that has a custom layout, a dialog containing a list, or [`startActivityForResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to the "picker" activity, use `setResult(int)`, and handle the result in `onActivityResult(...)` of the prior activity.

I think that using a dialog with a list is probably the easiest:

```
ListView listView = new ListView(context);
listView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(clickListener);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
// setup your dialog's listeners and title
builder.setView(listView);
builder.show();
```

Some notes:

1. yourAdapter is a ListAdapter that you have populated from your SQLite DB
2. clickListener is responsible for setting the result on the textview and closing the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setcontentview(R.layout.main);
dialog.setTitle("Title");
dialog.show();
```

in the main layout you can include whatever you need like list view or anything based on your purpose...This serves your purpose i think